# How use the mini-css-extract-plugin to combine imported css and css generated from scss in a single file?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm using `Webpack 4` and the `mini-css-extract-plugin` in a php application. I keep all the `css` styles I've written in `scss` files but, in some cases, when I import an external library, I import its css in the script where I use it. My end goal would be to have all the css styles in a single css file that I can manually include in a php view, but at the moment I get the scss in a file and the css from libraries in another.

My current webpack configuration is this:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
  style: './resources/assets/sass/style.scss',
  ...
},
 optimization: {
   splitChunks: {
     cacheGroups: {
       default: false,
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          minChunks: 1,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true,
        },
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
          //minChunks: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: { config: { path: 'postcss.config.js' } },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
plugins: [
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].css',
    }), 
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     noUiSlider: 'nouislider',
   }),
]
```

The `scss` styles work correctly, but then in one script I have this:

```
import 'nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';
```

Which is from a script included with `ProvidePlugin` and this css ends up in `vendors.css` file, while I would like it to be in `style.css` together with the rest.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
As suggested, I created a github repository recreating the issue:

https://github.com/carlotrimarchi/webpack-test

Comment: Create a minimal git repo which reproduces your issue, so we can take a look...

Comment: @Legends I edited my question adding a link to a minimal github repository. I included the whole `node_modules` directory, so simply running `npm run build` should be enough

Comment: Did you find solution? I have identical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@import '~nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';` to one of ur scss files.
No need to use ProvidePlugin for importing css.

The (**~**) symbol tells webpack to look into node_modules folder.
You can use this method for any css/scss files from node_modules folder.

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my question: the plugin `NoUiSlider` is imported with `ProvidePlugin`, the `nouislider.css` file is imported inside a script.

Comment: @Carlo import css using the above method in one of ur scss files

Comment: I just tried anyway your method and it doesn't work. With my current webpack configuration, importing the `nouislider.css` directly in the `main.scss` generates anyway two separate css

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You want:

> ...and this css ends up in vendors.css file, while I would like it to
>   be in style.css together with the rest.

Use Gautams answer. All this left, right confused me.
Just ref all the style files in one `scss` file, then they will get bundled together. I still don't get why you do a separate import of `nouislider` in `scripts.js`...

---

**First:**

```
entry: {
  style: './resources/assets/sass/style.scss',
```

`style.css` is not an entry-point to your application, it is `script.js` as it is the only js file in your project, beside `node_modules`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
 entry: {
        // style: './resources/assets/scss/main.scss',
        common: './resources/assets/js/script.js',
    },
```

**In wp4: plugins, vendor scripts, css files are not entry-points to your application! Don't add them under `entry`**

What you need to do:

1.) Change the your entry-point as mentioned above

2.) Remove the `optimization` section in your webpack.config.js. You don't need it.

3.) Remove `ProvidePlugin` (not needed)

4.) Import the styles in your entry file:

**scripts.js:**

```
import "../scss/main.scss"
import 'nouislider/distribute/nouislider.css';

console.log('test')
```

The styles are rendered in the order you import them.

WP4 automatically creates optimized output bundles for your app.
So for your little test repo and the adopted changes 1-4, you will get one `js bundle` and one `css bundle`.

[image]

Comment: I need the `optimization` because on the real website I have many entry points an many libraries in `node_modules`. Is it really a problem putting the scss as an entry point? I have many entry points and I need the same css in all of them

Comment: You could create a one `main.scss` file and there import all `css` and `scss` files you want to be part of it and finally only import `main.scss` in your entry scripts. You can keep the `optimization` part but for this little test repo it's not needed.

Comment: of course, but I wanted to keep the configuration as similar as possible to the actual one. Would it be an acceptable practice to create a fake `style.js` file simply to import the `main.scss` and the `css` and use it as an entry point?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not an entry-point shouldn't be used. Currently the webpack docs still point to wp v3. 
https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969678282085060608

Comment: the issue I have with these solutions is that it's not evident where the `scss` gets imported and I can't choose the generated filename. It's not a big deal, but it's weird that I end up having the `css` named as a script even when they are not related at all

Comment: Explain your issue [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues), they will help you out